# Is "chaperon" versus "chaperone" a US versus British English thing?

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography, dialects

I've noticed that "chaperone" can also be spelt "chaperon", without the "e" at the end.

Is this a case of American English simplifying a British English word, or something else? The original French seems to lack the "e".

Wiktionary mentions the two spellings, but doesn't explain why they exist.

Comment: I've pretty much always (in the US) seen it spelled "chaperone" (and pronounced with the associated "long" O).

Comment: The oddly-accented guy on [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/chaperon) pronounces the O halfway between long and short, a little bit like he's unsure which is correct.

Comment: (I strongly suspect that the e-added version is used because a long O is assumed.)

Comment: I've never seen "chaperon" in US English writing before.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [corpora](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available/2578#2578) I checked indicate that both forms are used on both sides of the Atlantic. The [BYU-BNC British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) has 32 instances of *chaperon* and 32 of *chaperone* from the 1980s to 1993. The [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) has 277 instances of *chaperone* and 60 instances of *chaperon* from 1990 to 2015. (I excluded the spoken sections.) So there are clearly some differences across time and space, but *chaperon* is actually older or more British or both; it's definitely not a new American simplified spelling.

Surprisingly to me, the Oxford English dictionary treats "chaperone" as merely a common error for "chaperon", not even listing it alongside the other variant spellings such as *chapperoon, shaparoon, shaparowne*. It gets a special note:

> [In the sense of a companion]... English writers often erroneously
> spell it *chaperone,* apparently under the supposition that it requires
> a feminine termination

If this is the actual origin of the spelling, I guess it would make it doubly erroneous now, since in modern usage the word is often gender-neutral.

But it's not clear that the *e* was intended to be a feminine termination. There are other words from French that don't refer to female people, but have definitely have gained an *e*, such as *[morale](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/morale?q=morale), [locale](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/locale?q=locale), [ladrone](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ladrone)* (the last one seems to be also taken from Spanish *ladrón*). An "extra" *e* also occurs in some words taken from other languages such as German (*[chorale](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/chorale?q=chorale), [ketone](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ketone)*). For most of these words, it seems to be connected to the stress or vowel quality of the last syllable. All the dictionaries I've found say that the primary stress in *chaperon(e)* falls on the first syllable, but some transcribe secondary stress on the third, and all seem to agree that it has an unreduced vowel (the Oxford English Dictionary gives the following three pronunciations: /ˈʃapərɒn/ /ˈʃapərɔːn/ /ˈʃapərəʊn/). This differs for example from [*apron*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/apron?q=apron) /ˈeɪprən/ which had the same suffix in French but was borrowed earlier and now has a reduced schwa vowel (or a syllabic nasal) in English.

Another possible source of confusion is that the Italian augmentative suffix -*one* is spelled with an *e*.  So English words taken from Italian often are spelled with a final *e,* which in many words is pronounced as a separate vowel (such as in *minestrone*) but in some words is silent, or optionally silent (*[trombone](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/trombone?q=trombone), [provolone](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/provolone), [calzone](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/calzone)*). (And in *[balcony](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/balcony?q=balcony),* it was respelled to *-ony*).

Comment: My pronunciation, and I've never heard usage noticeably inconsistent with it (U.S. midwest), is split between /'ʃæ:pərɤɯn/ (more likely when used as a verb) and /ʃæpər'ɤɯn/ (more likely when used as a noun).

Answer (score 9):

The variant "chaperone" appears to be from a mistake:

***[Chaperon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chaperon&allowed_in_frame=0):***

> - 1720, "woman accompanying a younger, unmarried lady in public," from French chaperon "protector," especially "female companion to a young woman," earlier "head covering, hood" (c. 1400), from Old French chaperon "hood, cowl" (12c.), diminutive of chape "cape" (see cap (n.)). "...
> - ***English writers often erroneously spell it chaperone, app. under the supposition that it requires a fem. termination" [OED].*** The notion is of "covering" the socially vulnerable one.

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chaperone%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cchaperone%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchaperone%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchaperone%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) "chaperone" is common both in AmE and BrE,
and is now the more common form [Ngrm](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chaperone%2Cchaperon&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cchaperone%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bchaperone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BChaperone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cchaperon%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bchaperon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BChaperon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCHAPERON%3B%2Cc0) both in AmE and BrE.

Comment: It may have started as an error, at least according to that source, but I think it should be considered the correct spelling in both American and British English because it is more common and more well-understood (as an American, I wouldn't even know what the `chaperon` variation meant without context, and I'd have assumed it was a typo).

Comment: @Keavon - as shown in my answer, the 'chaperone' variant is the more common both in BrE and AmE. It is interesting that it all started with a wrong assumption.

Comment: Fun fact related to the etymology; the Perrault version of *Le Petit Chaperon Rouge*/*Little Red Riding Hood* ends with the moral that young girls should not be without their caperon, a pun that would be obvious when one has just read the etymology above, but otherwise doesn't work in translation.

Comment: From a French-speaker perspective, I've always thought that English writers just wrote it like they pronounce it.  I've seen "prochain" written as "prochaine" even though the subject was masculine, for example.  They tend to pronounce the "n", resulting in the extra "e" when they write.

Comment: @MetalMikester: As an English-speaker who's learning French, what you say about "prochain/prochaine" definitely seems true (English speakers are inclined to pronounce the "n" as a consonant even when the word is masculine, which can cause them to mistakenly write it with an "e" in French). For English words borrowed from French, though, it's normal for "n" to be pronounced no matter how the word is spelled. For example, English "plain" comes from French "plain"; the "n" is pronounced, but no "e" is added. In some words, such as "pain" (from French "peine"), the French "e" is even removed.